# "Control commands (starting with a dot '.') cannot be served from the query endpoint unless they are .show control commands.",

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer, kql

I trying to execute Kusto function which is in .csl file through C# program, but I'm getting bad request error

> "Control commands (starting with a dot '.') cannot be served from the query endpoint unless they are .show control commands."

I tried using `executecontrol` command I got parsing error. please help

sample.csl -

```
.create-or-alter function Info_StampInfo(startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime) 
{
cluster(X).database('Y').['ClusterLog-ClusterBasicInfo']  | count
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the error message you've provided, I can *guess* that your C# program is trying to call `ICslQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(".create or alter function ...", ...)` instead of `ICslAdminProvider.ExecuteControlcommand(".create or alter function ...", ...)`.

If that's not a great guess, you may want to share: (1) a code snippet that shows what your C# program is running; (2) the full error message / stack trace for when you tried using `ExecuteControlCommand(...)`